# How to filter data which is Array of dictionaries and each dictionary contains NSSet object

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, predicate, nsset

I have `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionaries` and each dictionary contains `NSSet` object which is basically other entity as many to many relation in core data.
What I want is based on specific value of `NSSet` I want to filter my `NSMutableArray`. Please suggest, how to approach.

Answer (score 1):

NSPredicate to the rescue.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

         // I have NSMutableArray ...
        NSMutableArray *array  = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSArray        *result = nil;

        // ... of NSDictionaries ...
        // ... each dictionary contains NSSet object which is basically other entity ...
        NSDictionary   *dict1  = @{ @"name": @"Adam",
                                     @"age": @(47),
                                     @"children": [NSSet setWithArray:@[ @"Alan", @"Bobby", @"Chuckie" ]]};
        NSDictionary   *dict2  = @{ @"name": @"Bob",
                                     @"age": @(37),
                                     @"children": [NSSet setWithArray:@[ @"Brian", @"Chaz", @"Donald" ]]};
        NSDictionary   *dict3  = @{ @"name": @"Charlie",
                                     @"age": @(27),
                                     @"children": [NSSet setWithArray:@[ @"Caaaaaarl", @"Donnie", @"Eddy" ]]};
        // ... 
        [array addObject:dict1];
        [array addObject:dict2];
        [array addObject:dict3];

        // So, let's find children (stirngs) who contain 'd'
        // This should be Bob and Charlie.

        NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY children CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"D"];
        result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        NSLog(@"%@", result);
//          {
//              age = 37;
//              children = "{(\n    Brian,\n    Chaz,\n    Donald\n)}";
//              name = Bob;
//          },
//              {
//              age = 27;
//              children = "{(\n    Donnie,\n    Eddy,\n    Caaaaaarl\n)}";
//              name = Charlie;
//          }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can use NSPredicate to filter deep collections. The collection operators vary, depending on what you are trying to do. More informatiom available at the [Apple NSPredicate docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html).